# Biclustering and variable selection

Tags: clustering

Maybe this is a naive question so do not blame me. I wonder if biclustering is equivalent to perform a clustering then a variable selection (eventually followed by a new clustering)?
Do these approaches produce different results?

Answer (score 2):

There is not one single way of [biclustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biclustering), nor is there a single way of clustering and then variable selection. As such: there is no straightforward answer to your question.

However, the fact that different methods exist is already somewhat of a giveaway: there are plenty situations where this will not (necessarily) give the same result.

Unless you are in very fortunate situation (say, orthogonal data and similar requirements), doing two things "at the same time" (clustering and variable selection), and then sequentially generally does not render the same results (a simpler example is stepwise forward model building as opposed to some penalized model selection). In some cases (when it can be shown that the resulting sequences are Markov chains), this can be brought closer together by repeating the sequential steps. I suspect that some of the algorithms for biclustering actually come down to this (but I have not checked this).

Note that the wikipedia article linked above holds some nice references, as well as it points to the debate on the value of (the different methods of) biclustering.